# Запрет прямого запроса к файлу php и при этом чтобы через ajax можно было

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Есть задача сделать функционал статистики, файлу посылается id, где после получения id записывается статистика.

Как сделать защиту от "умника", который решит накрутить статистику напрямую обратившись к скрипту и подставит id.

Как защититься?

Comment: Надо копаться в сторону токена, там найдете нужный клад.

Comment: имеешь ввиду зашифровать какое-нибудь число в токен и потом использовать его как ключ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делаю вот так:

```
if(isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && ( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' ) && (check_valid(getenv("HTTP_REFERER")))){
.........
}
```

**Обновление**

Можно вроде даже без 3-го условия.